# IF UPDATE in trigger returns true when no rows were affected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why is the trigger executing the `update(col1)` block in the following:

```
USE tempdb
go
CREATE TABLE t1(id INT, col1 VARCHAR(10))
go
INSERT INTO dbo.t1( id, col1) VALUES(1,'aa'),(2,'sdf'),(3,'fg')
go
CREATE TRIGGER r_test ON t1 after UPDATE
AS
PRINT 'Trigger'
IF UPDATE(col1)
    PRINT 'col updated'
GO

UPDATE t1 SET col1='werwer' WHERE id=4
```

**output**

> col updated

I understand why the trigger executed but since `id = 4` doesn't exist, shouldn't `UPDATE(col1)` be returning false?

Answer (score 4):

Because `IF UPDATE(col1)` only checks if `col1` was referenced in the `UPDATE` statement. It does not check how many rows were affected, nor does it check if the value has actually changed.

**To not get the trigger to fire when zero rows are affected:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.r_test 
  ON dbo.t1 after UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
    ...
  END
END
```

Note that `MERGE` may complicate this - `@@ROWCOUNT` can be non-zero even if no rows are updated, only inserted/deleted ([more details here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)).

Instead you can:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.r_test 
  ON dbo.t1 after UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
  BEGIN
    ...
  END
END
```

**To determine if the value has changed:**

```
IF EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.t1 ON i.id = t1.id
    WHERE i.col1 <> t1.col1
);
```

This is grossly simplified; NULLs will complicate this, as will columns with encrypted values.

*Also, [please always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).*